# What the hell is this "gettingthere" tag? Crush! Kill! Destroy!

Tags: discussion, tagging

I spend a lot of time grooming our tag jungle here yet somehow I had not noticed this ugly beast lurking within until just now:

> [gettingthere](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gettingthere)

WTF?

I mean seriously, WTF?

It's a meta tag, which we know is bad, it's covered by existing tags like [transportation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transportation) and [routes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/routes).

And the fricken hyphen is missing!

And did I mention WTF?

Comment: Oh c'mon, don't be so harsh on our tag policy, we're, uh, gettingthere..

Comment: You're right I should sit back, relax, and propose the [tag:gettingbackhomeagain] tag (-:

Comment: Be nice, dammit!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct, this is a meta tag and not particularly useful. Deleted. System should auto-remove it in a few days.